# New website created in VVV doesn't appear

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, vagrant, vvv-wordpress

New websites created using `vv create`, doesn't appear in host, and I can't find them after creation.

I have a lot of websites created in vvv, however vagrant-hostsupdater could only find the default sites from vvv. And, I have this problem after an update to vvv 2.0.

Anyone knows how to fix this issue? 
How can I make my website - aluxh.dev found in the nginx?

```
==> default: [vagrant-hostsupdater] Checking for host entries
==> default: [vagrant-hostsupdater]   found entry for: 192.168.50.4 vvv
==> default: [vagrant-hostsupdater]   found entry for: 192.168.50.4 vvv.dev
==> default: [vagrant-hostsupdater]   found entry for: 192.168.50.4 local.wordpress.dev
==> default: [vagrant-hostsupdater]   found entry for: 192.168.50.4 src.wordpress-develop.dev
==> default: [vagrant-hostsupdater]   found entry for: 192.168.50.4 build.wordpress-develop.dev
```

Also, it has stopped prompt me for password when I do provisioning too. I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

I did further troubleshooting, and found out that by adding:

```
vvvtest:
  hosts:
    - vvvtest.com
```

into `vvv-custom.yml`, the vagrant-hostsupdater will be able to find my entry and start doing the mapping.

Anyone knows how can I make the site addition to `vvv-custom.yml` done automatically after `vv -c`?

Comment: The way i've always done it is to add the site to vvv-custom.yml as you described  then do `vagrant reload --provision`. I dont know about `vv -c` - never used that command